# elif command keeps repeating inside while command

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I put an `elif` statement in a while statement, and I expected that when it finishes what's inside it, it'd repeat the `while` command. What actually happens is the console spams "unknown command" indefinitely. How do I fix this?

```
while O == 0:
    if bla bla bla
        O = 1
    elif O != 1: #This should happen after it takes all if commands above me into account
        print('unknown command')
```

Comment: you missed the `:` after `if bla bla bla`, it sould be `if bla bla bla:`

Comment: @JoeR: clearly that's just a futzed statement, since `bla bla bla` isn't a valid expression either. Adding a colon there is not magically going to make this work.

Comment: It looks like "bla bla bla" is never true, so `O` never gets changed to 1, and so the `elif` part is always executed. BTW, it's preferred that you post actual testable code, not stuff like "bla bla bla". Also, `O` is not a great variable name - it's too easy to confuse it with zero, syntax highlighting notwithstanding.

Comment: If you need more help with this, please add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your O==0 is true, elif statement is also True (o!=1) unless if statement is True and O is changed to 1.
So when elif statement is executed, it goes to infiniteloop since the value of o is not changed inside elif. Or add a `break` after print in elif

Answer (score 1):

Clearly your `if bla bla bla` test isn't matching.

However, since `O == 0` is true, so is `O != 1`, and you never change the value of `O`, producing an endless loop. The endless loop prints out `'unknown command'` each iteration, filling up your console.

Comment: Ah, the if command in the text above was only to explain, I actually have the : written in the actual coding. So I realize that I just threw myself in an infinite loop, how do I just make the elif command repeat the entire script? Will i have to redo the entire idea?

Comment: @PopCar: I don't quite know what you are asking here. Only the `while` loop is repeated, not the whole script. If you need to repeat other things, you need to rethink your loop.

Comment: @PopCar: I don't mind either way, but know that you can pick only *one* answer as accepted; by marking Naiju's answer as accepted my answer is automatically unmarked again. :-) Pick the one that helped you the most (but neither is also allowed).

Comment: I wish I could choose both of you <_>, but the fact that he added the break command kind of fixed what I'm asking for, I would totally upvote your comment, but I don't have enough reputation for that. Eitherway, you've been great help, thanks!

Comment: Not a problem! It is a common misunderstanding with first-time Stack Overflow askers we see.